# Why using cv2.imread to read an image created by Wand from pdf file return all 255 for all RGB?

Tags: python, opencv, wand

I am trying to identify blobs of text in a pdf file. So say for example, there are different sections in an academic paper, and I want to identify the title as a section, the authors and addresses as a section, and the abstract as a section.

One solution i am thinking is to use cv2. I first convert pdf to a image using Wand using the following codes:

```
from wand.color import Color
from wand.image import Image as Img
with Img(filename='./files/paper.pdf', resolution=300) as img:
    img.background_color = Color("white")
    img.alpha_channel = 'remove'
    img.save(filename='test_file.jpg')
```

However, when I am trying to open the jpg file in cv2 with:

```
image = cv2.imread('test_file.jpg')

print image
```

the printout shows that all the values in that image is 255 for all pixels.

```
array([[[255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        ...,
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        ...,
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        ...,
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       ...,

       [[255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        ...,
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        ...,
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        ...,
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]]], dtype=uint8)
```

And then, when i want to use cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(), it just won't get it right.

What's going on? Was it because the pdf didn't get converted correctly into an image? But i tried

```
from PIL import Image
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test_file.jpg'))
```

, it returned all text to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See all the dots? The printing of the image is just showing a few pixels of the image. Assuming you have a pdf text document with a white background, it is safe to assume that all the edge pixels are white. The print will typically show you the corners of the image.

To show the image use

```py
image = cv2.imread('test_file.jpg')
cv2.imshow('Image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This will display the image in a window, and wait for you to press a key before disappearing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Andreas! Maybe a separate question, but since I am running this on aws EC2, I don't seem to be able to find a way to show the image, any suggestions?

Comment: Well it's hard to display an image in a terminal in such a way that it is helpfull. Especially a RGB image. If you convert it to gray, and use numpy's [set_printoptions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html), you can be able to display some more of it. Don't know how large your image is.

Answer (score 0):

Wand images are not numpy arrays and so cannot be simply opened in cv2. In Wand 5.3, there will be a way to import and export Wand images to and from numpy arrays.

In Wand 5.2, you can use import_pixels to convert a numpy array to a Wand image. In Wand 5.2, you can export a Wand image to numpy array that you should be able to use in cv2.

```
import numpy as np
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='rose.png') as img: 
    matrix = np.array(img)
```

matrix will be a numpy array that you should then be able to use in OpenCV